# SSLException: Connection has been shutdown:Operation timed out,

Tags: java, android-layout, android-studio, java-7

I'm regularly getting this error

> SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Operation timed out)

on android studio, how can I resolve this? My layout won't open.

Comment: This occurs when your keystore don't have the certificate of the requested secure url.

Answer (score 2):

I have been into same error in android studios while updating its components . 
After several hours i have resolved this issue. which i am going to share with you and others who ran into same problems .

Do the following:
1) Make sure you have updated latest Android Studio stable version.
2) Complete download the partial downloaded android sdks API's. 
[image]
3) [ important ] Install Repository and sync project from the Event logs shows error . Make sure to install lower versions first.Just scroll down logs and you can find lowest versions to be downloaded . If lucky like me :D  than the error will go by just Installing lowest Repository i.e 22.2.0(in my case)
[image]

4) Clean Project / Invalidate Caches and restart. Done!